# OpenCV (C,2.0) input points get messed up by internal function variable cast

Tags: c, function, opencv, malloc

```
double dist(CvPoint* a,CvPoint* b){
    double d;
    d = sqrt(pow((double) a->x- (double) b->x,2) + pow((double) a->y-(double) b->y,2));
    return d;
}
```

This simple little function is messing up the value of an external variable `pWorm1->HeadRef`, which is used as the the input argument `b` and is of type `CvPoint*`.

In the Code::Blocks debugger, as soon as the `d =` line is run, the values of the external variable `pWorm1->HeadRef->y` changes to gibberish, and I have no idea why. From other debugging steps, it does seem to have to do with the `(double)` cast itself.

Using OpenCV 2.0

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? I can't reproduce your problem (using Xcode). Also, I don't think the casts to `double` are necessary, since the values will be implicitly promoted to `double`.

Comment: Thanks Aurelius. Unfortunately, an SSCCE is not possible because the error occurs only for a small subset of frames that I am processing by OpenCV (less than 5 in 1000). I was hoping I made some kind of correctable memory mistake, or something simple to fix :(

Comment: Is `pWorm1->HeadRef` a double?

Answer (score 0):

**I was not able to reproduce the problem you described**, **but** there's no good reason for `dist()` to receive 2 pointers if this function is not modifying them. I mean, the `CvPoint` data type consumes only a few bytes of memory.

```
double dist(CvPoint a, CvPoint b){
    double d;
    d = sqrt( pow( (double)a.x - (double)b.x, 2) + 
              pow( (double)a.y - (double)b.y, 2) );
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, karlphillip. In fact, what you've described is exactly how I had the function to begin with. I only changed the inputs to pointers in an attempt to more precisely specify everything's memory address in case some overlap was causing the problem. 

As I mentioned in response to Aurelius, the mistake occurs only for a small number of frames in a movie I am processing. Therefore it's hard for someone else to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out the error has nothing to do with the dist function itself.
I set up the pWorm1->HeadRef variable in an extremely crappy way, giving it the local memory address of an internal function variable. Like this:

```
CvPoint HeadRef = cvPoint(xh,yh);
CvPoint TailRef = cvPoint(xt,yt);
pWorml->HeadRef = &HeadRef;
pWorml->TailRef = &TailRef;
```

So, let this be a lesson: Never rely on a memory address from within a function, as it will be freed as soon as the function completes.

Thank you all.